# Map function not working while passing props into React component (TypeScript, React and Next.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm new to TypeScript and Next.js. I've created an index page that gets the JSON data from the mock database and after it's returned, it is supposed to dynamically create a new Block component for each object in the array using the map function.

I know that the Block component outside of the map function displays but doesn't seem to be calling the Block component while running the map function. Any ideas?

This is my index page:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

import {Block} from 'components/text/block';


interface Props {
  games: [{
    _id: string;
    name: string;
  }]
}

const Home: NextPage<Props> = ({games}) => {
  console.log(games);

  return (
  <div>
    {games.map((g) => {
      console.log("Inside Map " + JSON.stringify(g.name));
      <Block key={g._id} name={g.name}></Block>
    })}
    <Block key={games[0]._id} name={games[0].name}></Block>
  </div>
  )
};

Home.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/games')
  const games = await response.json();
  return {games};
};

export default Home;
```

This is my Block component:

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  name: string;
  key: string;
}

export let Block: React.FC<Props> = ({name}) => {
  console.log("JSX Block " + name);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React component not rendering inside .map with if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59925252/react-component-not-rendering-inside-map-with-if-statement)

Comment: you are not returning anything from the map thus undefined gets rendered

Answer (score 4):

you are not returning anything from inside the map thus (implicit) `undefined` gets returned and renders nothing. you need to return your `Block` JSX element.

```
{games.map((g) => {
  console.log("Inside Map " + JSON.stringify(g.name));
  return <Block key={g._id} name={g.name}></Block>   // <----------------------
})}
```

Comment: YES! This was is. Thank you